# Nest.js custom pipe validator not working for method with @Req() and @Res() parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have defined custom pipe in Nest.js

```
 @Injectable()
export class QueryValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<GetDto> {
    public transform(value: GetDto, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): GetDto {
      console.log('TEST');
      (...)
      return value;
}
```

I'm using it in controller for certain GET method in controller A. I'm using Nest.js `@Query` decorator:

```
@Get()
@UsePipes(new QueryValidationPipe())
@UseFilters(new ExceptionFilters())
public async getMethod(@Query() query: GetDto) {
    (...)
}
```

And it works fine, for every request, pipe is logging test message to console. Now in controller B I'm using same decorator, but for method with underlying req and res object as parameters:

```
@Get()
@UsePipes(new QueryValidationPipe())
@UseFilters(new ExceptionFilters())
public async getMethodTo(@Req() req: GetRequest, @Res() res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    (...)
}
```

Here it doesn't work. Pipe transform method is not called despite requests being received by above method. What can be cause of this? I didn't found any word in documentation about pipes not working when @Req and @Res parameters are used in method.

And if that's the case (it seems it is), how can I fix this? I can't just use @Query query method parameter because I need to send back different headers depending on query param.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes only work for `@Body()`, `@Param()`, `@Query()` and custom decorators in the REST context. [There's a brief mention here](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#pipes), but that should definitely get added to the docs.

Technically, you could make a custom decorator for `req` and `res` and get pipes to run for them.

```js
export const ReqDec = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request;
  },
);
```

And then use it as `@ReqDec()`

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm getting the parameter value as `undefined` for the request.

Comment: @danielgi are you using HTTP as a transport engine, or something like GrpahQL on top of HTTP?

Comment: thank you for your response, I'm using  HTTP as a transport engine and using it like 
 `@ReqDec()private request: any;` and I'm trying to getting it in the transform function

Comment: That looks like it should be fine, honestly. If you can get me access to code I can take a look

Comment: Thank you! I solved it with injecting the request to the pipe CTOR instead.